# Как создать ahk скрипт для запуска yandex music встроенного в windows

Tags: autohotkey, microsoft-store, яндекс-музыка

У меня есть бот, который по определенным командам запускает разные приложения, но с Яндекс Музыкой проблема, так как она скачивается из Microsoft Store и просто указания нахождения файла не помогает.

Попробывал "Run yandexmusic:" команду, но она не ничего не делает